# Emit a signal when any button is pressed

Tags: python, pyqt5

In a pyqt5 app I want to untoggle a button when any other button is clicked.

Is it possible to have a signal emitted when any button inside a layout or a widget is clicked?

I can connect each button click to an untoggle function but that would be hard to maintain if the buttons ever change. Is there a clean way to achieve the same functionality without having to connect the buttons one by one?

Comment: With "untoggle a button", do you mean *a specific button"? Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Consider looking for [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) also.

Comment: Check out [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html). I use it quite a bit. There is some overhead to add buttons to a group. If one button in a group is clicked, the buttonClicked signal is emitted. QButtonGroup can be created in QtDesigner/Creator and you can add buttons to the group in Qt Designer/Creator

Comment: Do you really want literally *any* button in the *entire application* to untoggle the target button? Or do you only want to limit it to all the buttons within a *specific container/parent widget*? Also, what about keyboard/shortcut activation? `QButtonGroup` seems to be the optimal solution here, since it's flexible enough to handle all use-cases.

Answer (score 3):

How to point out a possible solution is to inherit from the button and implement the indicated logic, but in the case of Qt it can be taken advantage of the fact that the clicked signal is associated with the QEvent.MouseButtonRelease event when a button is pressed. Considering the above, notify can be used to implement the logic:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QCoreApplication, QEvent
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractButton,
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class Application(QApplication):
    buttonClicked = pyqtSignal(QAbstractButton)

    def notify(self, receiver, event):
        if (
            isinstance(receiver, QAbstractButton)
            and receiver.isEnabled()
            and event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease
        ):
            self.buttonClicked.emit(receiver)
        return super().notify(receiver, event)


def main(argv):
    app = Application(argv)

    view = QWidget()
    lay = QVBoxLayout(view)

    special_button = QPushButton("Special")
    lay.addWidget(special_button)

    for i in range(10):
        button = QPushButton(f"button{i}")
        lay.addWidget(button)

    view.show()

    def handle_clicked(button):
        if button is not special_button:
            print(f"{button} clicked")

    QCoreApplication.instance().buttonClicked.connect(handle_clicked)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: This solution is interesting because it is compatible with using qt designer with default buttons and, it doesn't require to maintain button groups.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is added functionality for an existing type.  This suggests that you want to write an extension of the Button class.  Write a class that inherits from `Button`.  Write your own function to handle button clicks: this function will call your `toggle` function and then call the parent's button click handler.

Comment: Building up on your idea. Making a class that inherits from the widget class and having a search function that connects every clicked signal from its child widgets (the buttons) to an other signal would be a valid solution?

Comment: Sure; that should work the same way.  The important concept is that  you're extending an existing type -- write a child class and add what you need.  For everything else, just defer to the parent.