# How to get signal from QPushButtons which is inside grid layout?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyside6

I have a GUI that looks like the below which has many QPushButtons added dynamically during run time:

[image: scroll widget]

Each of these buttons is added inside `gridlayout` and later image is embedded in each button. What I want is to get the object name or image name. How do I do that?

**Edit 1**:

There is a suggestion to use `self.sender()` to get the widget's object name as mentioned in this link [PyQt: Getting which button called a specific function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823841/pyqt-getting-which-button-called-a-specific-function) which uses `self.button.clicked.connect(self.function)`. However, in my case, I have loaded more than 100 buttons, and emitting a signal from each of these buttons is not possible.

**Edit 2**:
What I am trying to implement is closer to what is mentioned in this post

[Emit a signal when any button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790247/emit-a-signal-when-any-button-is-pressed)

Request to reopen the question.

Comment: You create buttons dynamically as I understand. So it isn't clear at all what is the problem to link hundreds signals with 1 slot.

Comment: I would like to emit signal from dynamically created buttons when they are clicked.

Comment: And what a prolbem with it? there are no problem at all to connect dynamically created button with a slot.

Comment: How is it possible to apply `self.button.clicked.connect(self.function)` for each button so that I know which button is emitting signal?

Comment: How did you create buttons? in for-loop?

Comment: Yes. Using for loop and added in to gridlayout in a dedicated function. Saw your answer. Will try and revert back.

Comment: Your code has helped me to get what exactly I want. I don't know why people have closed this thread though it is not relevant to other questions mentioned as duplicates...

Comment: I cant vote to reopen it unless you show your code.

Comment: Will post it soon